# How to make Rails load a plugin *after* the application code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

I'm trying to write a plugin that defines a MongoMapper model. The problem is that when I run `script/console`, I get this error:

`/home/helder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/mongo_mapper-0.8.2/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:29:in`
``database':NameError: uninitialized class variable @@database_name in MongoMapper::Connection`

which leads me to think that it's trying to load my plugin model before setting up the database connection. How do I make it load the plugin *after* the rest of my application code?

Comment: Do you require the plugin in environment.rb?

Comment: No, the plugin is loaded with all other plugins during start up, in alphabetical order (that's the default behavior when you don't declare any plugins explicitly in `environment.rb`). The problem here is that, when Rails is using ActiveRecord, it sets up the db connection *before* loading either gems or plugins. But mongomapper is a gem and doesn't set up the db upon loading: you have to do it in an initializer, *after* all plugins are loaded.

Comment: Could you post your initializer, please?

Comment: are you using mongo as the primary/only database, or as a secondary database/ a sub model relationship?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will try to address both the error I encountered as well as the general question as stated in the title.

### The specific error

I figured out what the problem was. As I said in a comment above, the problem is that Rails (2.3.8), when using ActiveRecord, first sets up the database connection, then loads gems, then plugins (in this order). So if you have any plugins that need to access the database during their initialization (that is, inside the plugin's `init.rb` or some other file `require`d by this one), everything works fine.

But when using MongoMapper, Rails loads MongoMapper's *classes* together with all other gems/plugins, but doesn't set up its connection (Rails doesn't do it, and the plugin doesn't trigger that itself either). The way currently recommended on [MongoDB's documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started) is to create an initializer like this:

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "#myapp-#{Rails.env}"

if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
   PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
     MongoMapper.connection.connect_to_master if forked
   end
end
```

But since plugins are initialized *before* files in `config/initializers` are run, if you try to define a MongoMapper model, as soon as it gets to a call that access the database (like a call to the `key` class method), BOOM. You get the error quoted in the question.

One way to solve this is to **not** require in `init.rb` the files that need the database, but rather only add them to the load path (if they're not in `lib/` or `app/models`, which Rails automatically adds to the load path). That way, the models will only be `require`d by Rails' auto class loader when they are referenced, which will usually be inside your application code. By then, the db connection will already be set up. Of course, this only works if you indeed **don't** need to reference these classes during your plugin's initialization. Otherwise, read on.

### The general question

**How to make Rails load a plugin *after* the initialization code?**

On your plugin's `init.rb`, throw *anything* that needs waiting inside this block:

```
config.after_initialize do
  # require my models
  # do this
  # do that
end
```

That `config` variable is the same passed to the block which is passed to `Rails::Initializer.run` inside your `config/environment.rb` file, and is made available to your plugin's `init.rb` by Rails at no extra cost.

Anything you put inside that block will be executed (by [`Rails::Initializer#after_initialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Initializer.html#M002055)) **after** everything is finished loading and getting initialized, but **before** any requests come in. Enjoy.